# RDS instance and corresponding EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have few EC2 and RDS instances running in AWS account.

I want to find out which EC2 is using which RDS instances ?
Is there any way to find this from console ?

I dont have access to application/services running inside these EC2 so i cannot check it.

Comment: You could look at the Security Groups on the Amazon RDS database and see which EC2 instances or other security groups have been permitted access. If your security is tight, this would show the information you need.

Comment: I think you could also use [vpc flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to monitor traffic to your rds. Then, based on the logs you could identify sources of the traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**:

1. Make sure [AWS VPC flow logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) are enabled, if not then enable them.
2. Go to [AWS CloudWatch logs insights](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/) and select AWS VPC flow log group, to run query on
3. Execute following AWS CloudWatch logs insights query;

`fields srcAddr | filter interfaceId='<elastic network interface id here>' and dstPort=<database connection port here> and action='ACCEPT' | stats count(*) as connection_count by srcAddr | sort connection_count desc`

where,

interfaceId - is the network interface id of the RDS instance usually it is prefixed with eni-

dstPort     - is the database port number, which is used by the application for database connectivity

srcAddr     - is the ipv4 address of the network interfaces, which are/were successfully connected to database on dstPort

You can also modify this query to fetch records for more than one RDS databases

4. Go to [advanced query feature of AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/query-your-resource-configuration-state-using-the-advanced-query-feature-of-aws-config/) and execute following query for IPv4 address from Step 3)

`SELECT configuration.attachment.instanceId WHERE resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface' AND configuration.privateIpAddress='<ipv4 address here>'`

where,

configuration.attachment.instanceId - is ec2 instance id

configuration.privateIpAddress      - is the primary private IPv4 address of the network interface attached to ec2 instance

You can also modify this query to fetch records for more than one ec2 and network interfaces

OR

**Option 2**:

You can enable [AWS RDS Performance Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.html) and view the connected client(s) on the Dashboard

OR

**Option 3**:

You might have ways provided by the specific database vendor that you are using, but for that you need to connect to individual database and fetch details. So, this is time consuming option.

OR

**Option 4**: Bit more for your use-case

Use [AWS VPC traffic mirroring](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-traffic-mirroring/)

Comment: Thanks This is really helpful.But i have one question i dont find any IP or ENI attached to RDS instance.DOes RDS have an ENI attached if yes where to find it?

Comment: If you have per RDS specific dedicated security group, then you can use that security group to find out associated network interface. else please refer [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=804327) post of AWS forum.